# Queries return results that don't add up

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors;
1274360
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where length(Name)<1;
0
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where length(Name)>=1;
516738
```

The above doesn't make sense. Can anyone explain why the second and third query don't give me all the rows in the table?

I know that none of the names have NULL in them, but just to make sure I queried it and it also returned 0

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where Name==NULL;
0
```

Comment: 1: `count 0` means there is no authors where length(Name) <1.....
2: `count 0` means there is no authors where Name == NULL.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better check for `NULL`s with:

```
select count(*) from authors where Name is NULL;
```

And read about three valued logic. You can not check with operator `==` , because `NULL <> NULL`.

Comment: really strange OP asked: `Can anyone explain why the second and third query don't give me all the rows in the table?`

Comment: @KhurramAli, what did you see strange here?  If you have 3 rows, (jordan),(null),(null) then filtering where len(name) >= 1 will return 1 because the result of len(null) is null. The counts didnt sum up because OPs filteres didnt consider null values.

Comment: OP was asking about `why the second and third query don't give me all the rows in the table?` and you answer him about null comparision that Use `IS NULL` instead of `=NULL`

Comment: And why do think second and third select didnt give as much as first? Because of NULLs in name column. And the OP said that there is no rows with NULL, but his che king was incorrect. I wrote correct checking after that OP has probably found missing count. It is so straightforward. I dont understand what is problem here.

Answer (score 1):

**Following Query gives you Total Count of Authors 
    Which is `1274360` Authors in your table**

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors;
1274360
```

**Following Query gives you Total Count of those authors whose name's length is less than 1 and your query gives `0` count because in your authors table you don't have such authors whose name length is less than 1**

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where length(Name)<1;
0
```

**Following Query gives you Total Count of those authors whose name's length is  greater than equal  to 1 and your query gives `516738` count because in your authors table you have such authors whose name length is greater than and equal  to 1**

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where length(Name)>=1;
516738
```

**Following Query gives you Total Count of those authors whose name is null
and you don have any authors that is why you get `0`**

```
sqlite> select count(*) from authors where Name =NULL;
0
```

> **Note:** for Null checking you should do something like this

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authors WHERE Name IS NULL;
      /* to get count of  all not null name use IS NOT NULL */
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authors WHERE Name IS NOT NULL;
```